# CometD/Bayeux client for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cometd, bayeux

Im looking for a Bayeux/CometD client for the iPhone. Objective-C implementation would work. Any idea where I can get it from? or any idea how I can create one cometD client for iphone .

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a `give me the codez` website. If you need someone to create a `CometD Client` (whatever that is) for you, go to http://peopleperhour.com. Also, you're not showing that you have done any research at all but expect other people to do it for you. That's not cool.

Comment: Mr. Schiefer , I have already searched for it , and I decided to port the java script one to objective-c but it is not the best way still I have problem with it cause http behavior is not built for streaming !!! If you dont know the answer don't vote for nothing !

Comment: I will vote wherever I see it as necessary, thank you. For your information, a downvote means: This question shows no research effort; it is unclear or not useful. Do you show research effort? Is your question clear? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This one](https://github.com/ddunkin/cometclient) can be a good start.